# Obtener el ID o nombre de Sesión en Joomla en php

Tags: php, joomla3

Mi consulta es sobre la sesión de joomla, cuando hay una red y varios usuarios se conectan. Hicimos pruebas y vemos que si hay de 4 personas en adelante el código tira el ID inadecuadamente, ejemplo yo soy el id 42 y a veces me aparece el ID 128 u otro ID de otra persona. ¿Es posible solucionar este problema?

Adjunto el codigo

```
<?php

define('_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."" ); 
define( 'DS','/' );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE.DS. 'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE.DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
require(JPATH_BASE.DS.'libraries/joomla/factory.php');

$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();

jimport( 'joomla.session.session' );
$session                =& JFactory::getSession();

$user =& JFactory::getUser();
echo "USER ID:".$user->id;
?>
```

Comment: Cabe la posibilidad de que sea por problemas de caché

Answer (score 0):

Revisa que la sesión que tienes en el lado servidor sea la misma que estés leyendo del lado cliente.

En el lado servidor puedes obtener el id de la sesión actual con `$session->getId()`, luego tendrías que pasar dicho id al cliente y si necesitas leerlo de nuevo en el lado servidor, usa algo así:

```
$options = ["id" => $input->session_id];

$session = JFactory::getSession($options);
```